# ImageView is still null, after findbyView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, nullpointerexception

Hey im trying to get a List working, in that case i have a xml defined item, which i inflate in a extended ArrayAdapter. But after i have inflated the xml, then when i try to grab the imageview, it returns null by findviewbyid...
Here is xml for the item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/product_item_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="if no image avail show this"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/product_item_imageview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Method that instatiates the item:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        SimpleListItem item= items.get(position);
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.product_item, null);
        if(item.getPicture()!=null)
        {
            ImageView imgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.product_item_imageview);
            String picturePath = item.getPicture();
            Bitmap picture = ImageManager.get(getBaseContext(), picturePath);
            imgVw.setImageBitmap(picture);
        } else {
            TextView txtVw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_item_textview);
            txtVw.setText(item.getText());
            txtVw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: ImageView imgVw = (ImageView)v. findViewById(R.id.product_item_imageview);

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, just found it myself. didnt know that was how inflater worked. Great day to learn more stuff :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a,

```
  ImageView imgVw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_item_imageview);
```

also the same for `TextView`,

```
 TextView txtVw = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_item_textview);
```

Use `View v` for getting `ImageView` and `TextView` from your inflated xml file.

Answer (score 1):

//you are inflating layout in a view v so you need to get them by

```
ImageView imgVw = (ImageView)v. findViewById(R.id.product_item_imageview);


TextView txtVw = (TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.product_item_textview);
```